# How to establish a secure socket connection with the c++ library websocket++?

Tags: sockets, c++11, ssl, websocket, boost-asio

I can establish a regular WS connection using the utility client here, https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/tutorials/utility_client/step6.cpp

However I need to attempt a secure WS connection and have replaced the config with the config below and linked the required libraries.

`typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_tls_client> client;`

My handler looks like:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context> context_ptr;

// part of class connection_metadata
static context_ptr on_tls_init(websocketpp::connection_hdl) {
    context_ptr ctx = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ssl::context>(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);

    try {
        ctx->set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3 |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout <<"Error in context pointer: "<< e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return ctx;
}

// part of class websocket_endpoint 
con->set_tls_init_handler(bind(&connection_metadata::on_tls_init,metadata_ptr,std::placeholders::_1));
```

When I attempt the following  line to get connection:

```
client::connection_ptr con = m_endpoint.get_connection(uri, ec);
```

I receive:

> Connection creation attempt failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue thanks to: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/websocketpp/SimAUzwZUVM

I had to make `on_tls_init` a static function and use it like so (before get connection) :
`m_endpoint.set_tls_init_handler(connection_metadata::on_tls_init)`

where `m_endpoint` is a client object.